# How to use array.map function asynchronously to update each item with a value from Sqlite3 database?

Tags: node.js, arrays, sqlite, async-await, promise

I'm in a learning process of node.js/react-native and I am stuck with `async / promises`.

I have a Sqlite3 database and a JSON file containing a list of foods. I need to update a single property for each food with a value from my sqlite3 database.

My foods file (`coffee.json`) look like this :

```js
[
    {
        "Description": "Candies, dark chocolate coated coffee beans",
        "Measure": "1.0 serving 28 pieces",
        "Caffeine(mg)Per Measure": 336,
        "MeasureValue": 336,
        "MeasureUnit": "mg",
        "fdc_id": 1,
        "index": 0
    },
    {
        "Description": "Beverages, THE COCA-COLA COMPANY, NOS energy drink, Original, grape, loaded cherry, charged citrus, fortified with vitamins B6 and B12",
        "Measure": "16.0 fl oz",
        "Caffeine(mg)Per Measure": 163,
        "MeasureValue": 163,
        "MeasureUnit": "mg",
        "fdc_id": 169634,
        "index": 1
    },
....
]
```

I'm trying to use `foods.map` with an `async` function, and I get `undefined`:

```js
async function UpdateFoods(fileSource) {
  const fs = require('fs');
  const file = fileSource;

  const foods = require(`${fileSource}`);

  const ufoodsPromises = foods.map(async food => {
    const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
    let query = `SELECT  fdc_id   FROM food f WHERE  description = ?`;

    let db = new sqlite3.Database('/home/smichi/Coding/fdadata/fdadb.db');
    db.get(query, [`${food.Description}`], (err, row) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        return row ? {...food, fdc_id: row.fdc_id} : 1;
      }
    });
  });

  const results = await Promise.all(ufoodsPromises);
  console.log(results);
}
UpdateFoods('../foodsdata/caffeine.json');
```

Executing UpdateFoods function will result in :

```sh
smichi@smichi-HP:~/Coding/Topfoods/src/Tools$ node updateId.js
[
  undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined
]
```

Although `console.log(row)` returns the wanted result. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it is returning a list of `undefined` is that the `db.get(...)` call returns the row inside of its own parameter function, rather than the `foods.map(...)` function, and nothing is returned in the `foods.map()` function.

In order to return the actual row, assuming that `db.get()` does not return a promise, you need to wrap it and return your own promise:

```js
async function UpdateFoods(fileSource) {
  const fs = require('fs');
  const file = fileSource;

  const foods = require(`${fileSource}`);

  const ufoodsPromises = foods.map(async food => {
    const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
    let query = `SELECT  fdc_id   FROM food f WHERE  description = ?`;
    let db = new sqlite3.Database('/home/smichi/Coding/fdadata/fdadb.db');
    
    // wrap the call in a promise and use resolve/reject to return your data.
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      db.get(query, [`${food.Description}`], (err, row) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(row ? {...food, fdc_id: row.fdc_id} : 1);
        }
      });
    });
  });

  const results = await Promise.all(ufoodsPromises);
  console.log(results);
}
UpdateFoods('../foodsdata/caffeine.json');
```